Does the word "spoils" include cattle?
I have a text about a king from the Old Testament. God commanded him not to take any of the possessions of the tribe he was fighting against, but he kept for himself a small share. He kept

the best of the sheep, and of the oxen, and of the fatlings, and the lambs, and all that was good, and would not utterly destroy them (1 Sam. 15:1 KJV)

Now, spoils is defined by dictionaries as meaning:

goods, advantages, profits, etc. that you get by your actions or because of your position or situation (Cambridge)


The spoils of something are things that people get as a result of winning a battle or of doing something successfully. (Collins)

Thing is, most examples of spoils offered in the dictionaries refer to inanimate objects or abstract concepts.
My question is, can I refer to cattle as spoils in the context I have given? Are there any similar examples of spoils?

The Samuel I story is itself a good example that livestock are part of the spoils of war. In that case, he was instructed specifically to destroy, not take home, the spoils.

@YosefBaskin Yet I could not find an explicit use of the word "spoils" even in the Bible.

Everything you can get your hands and steal after battle is your spoils.

@fev please see 106 Verses About Spoil from 29 Books although none of them use the plural 'spoils'.

In particular, Numbers 31:9: "took the spoil of all their cattle, and all their flocks, and all their goods."

... see Merriam-Webster for the singular use of the noun: plunder taken from an enemy in war or from a victim in robbery.

You may not see cattle mentioned as spoils as much simply because jewels and other small things are easier to carry away. So those are more common.

None of the definitions I can find say "spoils" refers to inanimate objects. Cattle and other livestock were possessions, and there are plenty examples where they are referred to as "goods", example example, and Douay-Rheims even says "Excepting women and children, cattle and other things, that are in the city" All easily Googlable.

OED spoil(s)

I.Senses relating to booty or plunder.
I.1. Goods, esp. such as are valuable, taken from an enemy or captured city in time of war; the possessions of which a defeated
enemy is deprived or stripped by the victor; in more general sense,
any goods, property, territory, etc., seized by force, acquired by
confiscation, or obtained by similar means; booty, loot, plunder.

Cattle are goods - the very word "cattle" is cognate with "chattel".

Aside from tribute, the Axumite king derived his income by appropriating the lion’s share of the spoils of war. Cattle constituted a substantial portion of the latter. (The Early State edited by H. J. M. Claessen, Peter Skalník)

